# R: Plot smaller clusters from hclust

Tags: r

I have 250 objects and I used `h <- hclust(distance.matrix, method = "single")` to obtain a `hclust` object. If I plot the dendrogram from `h`, it is just a mess since there are too many objects and the labels just get squashed together.

Suppose I am interested in particular groups of cluster

Now, I know we can use `cutree` to cut a tree, e.g., as resulting from hclust, into several groups by specifying the desired number(s) of groups.

But how can I obtain a dendrogram for those smaller groups of clusters in R separately?

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would help here, but if you know which objects fall w/i a given cluster, can't you just perform another `hclust` on just those objects & plot that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could convert your `hclust` object into a `dendrogram` and use `cut` (see `?cut.dendrogram` for details):

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
plot(hc)
```

[image]

```
## cut at height == 100
d <- cut(as.dendrogram(hc), h=100)
## cut returns a list of sub-dendrograms
d
#$upper
#'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 2 members total, at height 152.314 
#
#$lower
#$lower[[1]]
#'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 16 members total, at height 77.60502 

#$lower[[2]]
#'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 34 members total, at height 89.23209 

par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(d$lower[[1]])
plot(d$lower[[2]])
par(mfrow=c(1, 1))
```

[image]